# Laravel Carbon throws error The format separator does not match

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, laravel-5

I'm, trying to format a date into (Dayname Date Month) and I'm using Carbon for this but it return an error **Carbon The format separator does not match** here is a sample of DB data 2017-02-09 18:30:00.

Below is my code

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('l j F', $matchArr['matchTime'])->toDateTimeString()
```

Comment: You can also use `date("D M j", $matchArr['matchTime']);` for o/p of `Thu Mar 15`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to convert DB date "2017-02-09 18:30:00" to (Dayname Date Month) just use the php date function:

```
date("D d M", strtotime("2017-02-09 18:30:00"));
//outputs "Thu 09 Feb"

date("D d M", strtotime($matchArr['matchTime']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the value you're passing as your 2nd argument is a string `2017-02-09 18:30:00`, Carbon will throw this error because the format you've specified as the 1st argument - `l j F` - doesn't match the format of the value you're passing as your 2nd argument.

`2017-02-09 18:30:00` has format `Y-m-d H:i:s` - i.e. the following should work:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-02-09 18:30:00');
```

> N.B. 1: In Carbon, the error `The format separator does not match` often comes up if you mix up your order of arguments - i.e. if you put the time, followed by the format. (Thought this was worth worth mentioning for anyone else who comes across this - an easy mistake to make!)

> N.B. 2: Carbon uses the same date time formatting as native PHP DateTime: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 1):

So I just end up using native date function

```
date('l j F', strtotime($matchArr['matchTime']))
```